# Sorting on tuple in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, tuples

Please help me with sorting on tuple multiple parameter.

```
Tuple = (Option[String],Option[String],Option[String])
```

**Example:**

```
val lst:List[(Option[String],Option[String],Option[String])] = List(
  (Some("a"),None,None),
  (Some("b"),None,None),
  (Some("a"),Some("a"),None),
  (Some("a"),Some("b"),None),
  (Some("a"),None,Some("a")),
  (Some("a"),None,Some("b")),
  (Some("a"),None,Some("c")),
  (Some("a"),Some("a"),Some("a"))
  )
println("Sorted list = " + lst.sortBy(e=> (e._1,e._3,e._2)).mkString("\n"))
```

**Original output**

```
 Sorted list= (Some(a),None,None)
  (Some(a),Some(a),None)
  (Some(a),Some(b),None)
  (Some(a),None,Some(a))
  (Some(a),Some(a),Some(a))
  (Some(a),None,Some(b))
  (Some(a),None,Some(c))
  (Some(b),None,None)
```

**Expected output:**

```
(Some(a),None,None)
(Some(a),Some(a),None)
(Some(a),Some(b),None)
(Some(a),None,Some(a))
(Some(a),Some(a),Some(a)) - This line should be placed at last but one position 
(Some(a),None,Some(b))    - These two lines
(Some(a),None,Some(c))    - should come above the line
(Some(b),None,None)
```

In words, first element in tuple always is "Some" not "None". Second and third elements might have value "None".

Output should be sorted with first element, then all "Some" values from second element and all "None" values from third, then all "Some" values from third element and "None" elements from second one. After that, sorted by second and third elements(Both values are "Some" not "None"). Expected output shows this.

Simple sorting with each element wise in tuple not working as expected.

Comment: Why `e._1._1`? Shouldn't it just be `e._1`?

Comment: You'd better refactor your tuple as a case class, and implement `math.Ordering` for, that would greatly improve the readability.

Comment: I don't see a clear difference in the Example and the Expected output. Can you make more clear which line is not as expected?

Comment: Didn't get why `a,None,None` < `a,z,None` < `a,None,b` shouldn't it be `a,None,None` < `a,None,b` < `a,z,None`?

Comment: I find your heavy usage of the 'get tuple' operator (`._X`), especially with `e._1._3` to be unreadable

Comment: Sorry for not giving clear example. Updated with example and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code

"Unsorted" the input a little bit, that you can see it's really sorting.

```
val lst:List[(Option[String],Option[String],Option[String])] = List(
  (Some("a"),None,None),
  (Some("b"),None,None),
  (Some("a"),Some("b"),None),
  (Some("a"),Some("a"),None),
  (Some("a"),None,Some("c")),
  (Some("a"),None,Some("a")),
  (Some("a"),None,Some("b")),
  (Some("a"),Some("a"),Some("a"))
)

def getValue(el : (Option[String],Option[String])) = {
  el match {
    case (None, None) => 0
    case (Some(a), None) => 1
    case (None, Some(b)) => 2
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => 3
  }
}

lst.sortBy(e => (e._1, getValue(e._2, e._3), e._2, e._3))
```

Sorting just after first Tuple, the "special Rule", 2nd Tuple and 3rd Tuple.

## Output

```
List((Some(a),None,None), 
     (Some(a),Some(a),None), 
     (Some(a),Some(b),None), 
     (Some(a),None,Some(a)), 
     (Some(a),None,Some(b)), 
     (Some(a),None,Some(c)), 
     (Some(a),Some(a),Some(a)), 
     (Some(b),None,None))
```

Output as expected.

Comment: @jony Just updated my answer now it should fit to your question. Perhaps it could be a little bit prettier, but it works, and thats important :-)

Comment: Simple, neat and clever. Thanks.